# WF HandleExternalEvent activity

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a HandleExternalEvent activity inside a workflow. But when event is raised, I want my HandleEventActivity to handle it in that way, to stay in the idle state, and not to proceed. How this can be solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in that State Activity, you could point the setstateactivity to the same activity so that it will be in same state till you raise some other events.

Comment: Yes, but it can be applied to State machine workflow, only. I have a sequential workflow, so SetStateActivity can not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HandleExternalEvent Activity inside EventHandlingScopeActivity, if there are multipe events you are waiting for.

Else use a dealy timer in the code for HandleExternalEvent Activity, so as the workflow goes in idle state.